# Parse notifications work on emulator but not Android device

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Hey guys I've been trying to figure out why my Parse notifications haven't been showing up when I use the test push to my device. I'll post my manifest and app file to see if you guys can see the problem

Here is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joeforbroke.fuse" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
                android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MIApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:parentActivityName="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.EditFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_friends"
            android:parentActivityName="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.RecipientsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipients"
            android:parentActivityName="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ViewImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_image"
            android:parentActivityName="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.joeforbroke.fuse.ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action          android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.joeforbroke.fuse" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the app file

```
package com.joeforbroke.fuse;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MIApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "PRETEND REAL KEY IS HERE", "PRETEND REAL KEY IS HERE");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();



    }
}
```

Comment: Is your device registered in your Parse Dashboard? Go to Installation class in Parse to see if your device and your emulator are there

Comment: @JorgeCasariego yep they both are

Answer (score 0):

Even though I changed my package name of my project I used very the original package name and that worked. Not sure how that works but sure.